# Issue comparing datetime objects in django html template

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

I am passing in class objects and a variable into my html template in Django

Using Classbased Views, I have

```
get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
   ...
   context['time'] = datetime.now()
   ...
   return context
```

I also pass in my objects using
`model = Object` and `context_object_name = 'obj'`

In my html template my comparison looks like this:

```
{% if obj.start_time > time %}
        <h1 style="color:white">ITS WORKING</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Regardless of whether I use >, <, or ==, the h1 template is never displayed.

I have used {{obj.start_time}} and {{time}} to ensure that there really are values attached to these variables, and I see both of the times displayed on the page. The values themselves work, but for some reason the comparison isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that `time` and `start_time` are not both timezone-aware or both timezone-naive. Display the times with the timezone information to check.